# Liquibase convert mssql to postgresql using .sql file

Tags: liquibase

I have .sql file from mssql. I want to convert the DDL/inserts to postgresql style. How can I achieve it using liquibae cli. I see examples of running generatechangelog on a database but not using a .sql file.

Answer (score 2):

You could:

1. create an empty mssql database
2. apply the .sql files to that database
3. run `liquibase generateChangelog` ensuring that you specify `--diffTypes=data` and `--changelog=generatedChangeLog.xml`
4. Examine the generatedChangeLog.xml to ensure it has the data insert statements you expect.
5. run `liquibase updateSQL` to generate the SQL you need for PostgreSQL

I've left out a lot of details - you'll need to specify the correct connection information for each of the different databases at each of the different steps.

I've recently seen another project called jOOQ that might be another way of approaching the problem - I have not used it myself, but it looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

@steveDonie your answer is correct. There is no way to migrate .sql files from one dialect to another one.